# How to set permissions for Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth, manifest

I'm new to Android development. I'm trying to get a simple HelloWorld app going on my (rooted) phone - and the app is trying to enable Bluetooth.

I've set the Bluetooth permissions in my manifest is as follows, but I'm getting a Permission Denial exception when I try to run the application on my phone via Eclipse:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.helloandroid"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">      
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:permission="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN">
            <activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7" android:minSdkVersion="5"></uses-sdk>
</manifest>
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the problem was here.

All I can say is that I reinstalled Eclipse and its plugins and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your help Mayra - I'll up-mark your answer because of your helpful and friendly approach.

Comment: Next time try to do "everything" logical and then reinstall, therefore your computer techniques will strengthen.

Answer (score 3):

The answer about what to include in your manifest.xml for bluetooth activity includes

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

The first three are of greater priority and as I'm sure you're aware there are different cases when each dependency may be required. Hope it helps with your setup!

Answer (score -5):

The element types in the manifest are ordered.  I think the uses-permission needs to be first under the  tag.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mayra. I've tried moving the uses-permission tag around in the file and it doesn't seem to fix the problem - and the example manifest files I've seen often seem to include the uses-permission tags at the bottom of the file - so I don't think that the location of the tag is critical.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right.  I had a problem with permissions before that I thought was solved by order, but I see other places in the documentation where things are out of order. What is the exact error message that you are seeing?

Comment: Down voted, because in SO, we vote-up for quality of answer. Unfortunately, in spite of best intentions, the answer is incorrect.